# How to get entire post content having post_id WITHOUT using FQL - .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i searched a lot for an answer to this question but i did not find any helpful resource. I am doing a post on my wall with "**https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id={0}&display=page&canvas=1&redirect_uri={1}**", works just fine, i posted on my wall and as a response i get a post_id in query string at my *redirect_uri* (i do the post with dialog).
Now what i cannot manage to do.. is to obtain the full post information with facebook graph, without using FQL, i found lots of examples of how to get it with FQL Select .. but i realy want to make this just with a Graph call. 
I do all these in .net, i tried on the facebook grapk explorer: this is the exact url: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/266888499999433/?method=GET&path=100002843173627_116703548434417 .
Using the http GET method and having access_token i get the answer i want but doing this from my code i don't succeed. if i do a GET to the http://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID i get an answer as string **false**...  and if i add the **?access_token=MY_ACCESSTOKEN** in querystring i get **error 400 bad request**.
i have a class with this method:

```
 public Facebook.JSONObject GetPostInfo(string postID)
    {
        //"&access_token=" + this.Token
        string url = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + postID ;
        string json = this.WebRequest(MyFacebookAPI.oAuthFacebook.Method.GET, url ,String.Empty);
        return Facebook.JSONObject.CreateFromString(json);
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.. i finally found the solution:

```
if (CanvasAuthorizer.Authorize())
        {
            var fb = new FacebookWebClient();

            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = txtMessage.Text;

            try
            {
                dynamic id = fb.Post("me/feed", parameters);
                lblPostMessageResult.Text = "Message posted successfully";
                txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;

                //get post id
                IDictionary<string, object> data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                data.Add("access_token", CanvasAuthorizer.FacebookWebRequest.AccessToken);
                dynamic thePost = fb.Get(String.Format("{0}", id.id), data);

                string post = String.Format("Post:{0} From: {1} Message: {2}", thePost.id, thePost.from.name, thePost.message);
                lblPostMessageResult.Text = Environment.NewLine + post;
            }
            catch (FacebookApiException ex)
            {
                lblPostMessageResult.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

where first part makes the post with "message"
and second part we get post with the id we got back from the post.

You need to have extended permissions: **publish_stream,read_stream** in order for this to work + adding the access_token  as parameter into the Get method.
I hope my post will help some people that have troubles getting it right.